# Having trouble passing an apostrophe or double quote through a clickable link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have some code that receives a string (that might have an apostrophe or double quote in it). On receipt of the string, a link is created to allow the user to utilize the string in an input.

I have created a mockup jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q8jorw26/1/) to demonstrate the problem in a simplified manner. In the real-world version it is much more complicated and the first input and use button don't exist - they are only in the fiddle to simulate the received string.

To test it, enter some text with an apostrophe in the "String with apostrophe" input and click the "Use" button. It will create a link after "Copied String" that says "Use filename". If you click that link, it should put the string into the second input. If there are no apostrophes it's fine, but apostrophes just won't work (you can see the error in the console: `SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break`).

If I rewrite the `$("#usespan").html()` line and switch all the `"` to `'`, then the apostrophe works, but the double quote doesn't.

How can I get it to work for both `"` and `'`?

Thanks!

Jsfiddle code (HTML):

```
<p>String with apostrophe : <input id="fn"> <input type="button" value="Use" id="usefn"></p>

<p>Copied String: <span id="usespan"></span><br><br><input id="final">
```

Jsfiddle code (JS):

```
$("#usefn").on("click", function() {
    var fn = $("#fn").val();
    fn = myHtmlEntities(fn);
    $("#usespan").html(' <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(\'#final\').val(\' '+fn+'\');">Use Filename</a>');
});

function myHtmlEntities(str) {
   return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g,'&apos;');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best solution is to replace the single quote for `\'` after the input is received. So, you would be adding `.replace(/'/g, '\'')` to

```
function myHtmlEntities(str) {
   return String(str).replace(/'/g, '\'').....
}
```

> [How to Work with Strings in
>   JavaScript:](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-strings-in-javascript)
>   The syntax of \' will always be a single quote...

Comment: Interesting. I would like to better understand why &apos; causes trouble, I thought using the & versions of special characters was always the way forward. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's because, when you escape the character, it clearly seperates it from other uses of the apostrophy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the third way of signifying a string - a backtick (`). This will also let you use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of your current string concatenation:

```
$("#usespan").html(`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#final').val(${fn});">Use Filename</a>`);
```

Note: this does not work in Internet Explorer. For a full list of browser support, see the [CanIUse page](https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals).

Comment: Unfortunately I have to support IE :(

Answer (score 0):

I dont seem to be able to break this in IE11. Either that, or I've entirely misunderstood you!

```js
        "use strict";
        function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
        function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}
        window.addEventListener('load', onWindowLoaded, false);

        function onWindowLoaded(evt)
        {
            byId('myInput').value = "\`whats wrong with this?\"!";
            byId('goBtn').addEventListener('click', onGoClicked, false);
        }

        function onGoClicked(evt)
        {
            byId('output1').innerHTML = '';
            var a = newEl('a');
//            a.innerHTML = "Use Filename";
            a.innerHTML = byId('myInput').value;
            a.href = "javascript:void(0)";
            a.setAttribute('data-text', byId('myInput').value);
            a.addEventListener('click', function(){byId('output2').value=this.getAttribute('data-text');}, false);
            byId('output1').appendChild(a);
        }
```

```html
String with apostrophe: <input id='myInput'/><button id='goBtn'>Use</button><br>
Copied String: <span id='output1'></span><br>
<input disabled id='output2'/>
```

Comment: I’m confused by this answer. You’ve rewritten the OP’s code almost completely. That doesn’t answer the question of how to get their code working...

Comment: @HereticMonkey - simply put, the text-string in question is assigned to a newly-created attribute of the link. When the link is clicked, the text is extracted and applied as needed. My code aims to demonstrate single quotes, double quotes and exclamation marks in a bid to show the apparently extraneous use of string-replacement gymnastics. You get it, you hold it, you blast it. The OPs question demonstrates no need for acrobatics and thus, I offer no show of them. Perhaps the question is (also?!) lacking...

Comment: I'm not sure where IE11 comes into this, other than in the response to @Jack Bashford's question, which is about in their solution, the template literals won't work in IE. I don't see template literals in your response, so I'm not surprised it works in IE. Additionally, the js in my original question, in the real world, is loaded by ajax and has other (code ownership) issues with adding listeners on the main page that I won't go into here, so I was looking for an inline solution like the one that I have. Thanks for the response anyway though!